# How to support XeTeX development and bugfixing with donation of money or hardware?

Tags: xetex

I failed to find a way to support Xe(La)TeX *directly*. I looked into https://tug.org/donate.html , https://sourceforge.net/projects/xetex , and https://www.dante.de .  Since the project seems to have only one active and one passive maintainer now, the most recent bugfix is from the spring of 2019, and there are [79 outstanding issues](https://sourceforge.net/p/xetex/bugs/?limit=100) as of now (2020-07-01), I feel they might need some help.  I cannot help them with working hours, but a donation of money or hardware could work if it can be made anonymous enough. Any ideas, ideally directly from the two maintainers?

Comment: I've migrated from meta: this is not about TeX-sx itself. It's borderline for the main site too, but perhaps is allowable.

Comment: XeTeX is currently unmaintained.

Comment: @HenriMenke  Not quite: it has an inactive maintainer.  That’s subtly different :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, if a developer doesn't provide a way to make a donation, then you can only ask them if they would like one. In the TeX world, almost all work is done by volunteers with day jobs, so cash is rarely the determining factor in whether they can devote time to a project.

In the specific case of XeTeX, as far as I know the work is largely 'done': there is maintenance but no plans for major change. LuaTeX is different, and is a rare case where paid development was done funded by community donations. (Today, LuaTeX is also largely 'done', though the ConTeXt developers continue to work on LuaMetaTeX.)

Comment: @Just_A_Man I wonder what exactly you mean by 'maintenance': that I know of, there are some long-standing issues in math mode, but otherwise XeTeX basically works 'as advertised'

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110084/discussion-on-answer-by-joseph-wright-how-to-support-xetex-development-and-bugfi).

Comment: Those kind of projects are founded by TeX groups. Being a TeX group member means that the project will get founded if the maintainer asks to. I'd suggest to send also a mail to Arthur Reutenauer, project maintainer AFAIK asking how you can help.